# DevExpress TextEdit - Mask for Negative Values

Tags: .net, regex, devexpress

Actually, I have a Devexpress TextEdit and I am displaying amount in that TextEdit.
I have set the Mask Properties of TextEdit like :

```
 - MaskType -> Numeric
 - EditMask -> n2
 - UseMaskAsDisplayFormat -> True
```

Now, I am getting an Output like :

```
 - For Postive Values -> 800.00
 - For Negative Values -> 800.00-
```

But,I want an Output for Negative Values like -800.00

Can Anyone Help Me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set: RightToLeft = true - right?
Please set RightToLeft = False & Properties.Appearence.TextOption = Far

=> When you in put negative value => **-800.00**

Answer (score 0):

The `n2` tells the `TextEdit` to display a numeric value with two decimals, but it does not say anything about the `CultureInfo` to use. (DevExpress controls, or any controls for that matter, are not responsible for the culture).

If you want all amounts in your application to use a specific culture, set it for each thread. You can use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`, or else pick one with something like `new CultureInfo("fr-FR")`.

In .NET 4.5, you can use the `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` property to change the culture of an AppDomain. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture.aspx).

In versions prior to .NET 4.5, you have to set it per thread.

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(theCultureString);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
```